# How to update/reload auto fill suggestions for UITextField when changing textContentType of that text field?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have simple definition of UITextField in my UIView:

```
let textField: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.font = UIFont.poppinsRegular.withSize(18)
    textField.textColor = .black
    textField.textAlignment = .left
    textField.tintColor = .black
    return textField
}()
```

and on user reactions I change it depending on user needs like this:

```
func showTextField(
    placeholder: String?,
    keyboardType: UIKeyboardType,
    textContentType: UITextContentType?,
    isSecureTextEntry: Bool
) {
    textField.placeholder = placeholder
    textField.keyboardType = keyboardType
    textField.textContentType = textContentType
    textField.isSecureTextEntry = isSecureTextEntry
    textField.reloadInputViews()
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

And for example, I change from `.postalCode` to `.givenName` and it doesn't work until I tap on it. Why? What to do to update it automatically?

Look at the screenshots:

This is what I can see when I first display my UITextField and set `.postalCode` textContentType. I can fill it, and it is ok.

[image]

But when I fill it, there auto fill should be reloaded to `.givenName`, but it doesn't want to be refreshed. It remains from previous type. Why?

[image]

When I simply tap on that UITextField it is correctly refreshed. What can I do to refresh it without tapping on text field?

[image]